# Кто-нибудь встречал в сети статистику ошибок по языкам?

Tags: статистика

Собственно, интересует вопрос:

*Каково количество исправлений кода на миллион строк исходника (в год, за все время жизни проекта и т.п.) в зависимости от языка?*

Поискал в гугле, но кроме весьма интересной [статистики по составу debian-а](http://debian-counting.libresoft.es/lenny/index.php?menu=Packages&order=slocs) и явно устаревшей [Estimating GNU/Linux's Size](http://www.dwheeler.com/sloc/redhat71-v1/redhat71sloc.html) ничего толкового не нашел. Причем в этих материалах о статистике ошибок в коде нет ни слова.

То ли нет такой статистики, то ли правильно сформулировать вопрос не удается.

Comment: Мне кажется, что статистика будет просто цифрами, ничего не выражающими, потому что миллион строк на Си это ядро линукс по состоянию примерно на 2008 год, а миллион строк на питоне уже какой-нибудь искусственный интеллект способный поработить мир.

Comment: @ReinRaus, ядро линукс примерно на 2008 год (Debian 4.0  (Etch) Package linux-2.6) это 4700345 строк на Си (а всего 4920797 строк).

Для питона я обнаружил такой [список](http://wiki.python.org/moin/LargePythonProjects) с немногими проектами крупнее 100000 строк.

Не думаю, что по функциональности (известности или, если хотите, влиянию на мир IT) хоть один из них можно сравнить с ядром Linux.

А может (конечно, провокационная идея) питон вовсе не годится для действительно серьезных, разрабатываемых **многими** людьми проектов?

Может миллион строк на питоне просто правильно работать не будет?

Comment: Это не совсем верно сравнивать С и Python по количеству строк.

Comment: Ввести подобный коэффициент будет сложновато. Все очень сильно зависит от задач (и ещё сильнее от программиста, который этот код пишет).

Comment: @KoVadim, @ReinRaus, вообще-то сам вопрос совершенно конкретный (есть у кого-нибудь **данные** про количество ошибок на N строк кода). 

Вы же начинаете говорить о критериях сравнения языков (а это совсем другая тема).

Собственно, меня реально интересует сравнение количества изменений (скажем за год) в программах среднего размера, написанных на Си и С++. Думаю, может кто-нибудь видел, может исследования где-то проводились.

Формулируя вопрос, не стал конкретизировать, просто не хотел заострять, но все равно пришлось. А то уже пошли сравнения несравнимого (языков совсем разного назначения).

Comment: > Собственно, меня реально интересует сравнение количества изменений (скажем за год) в программах среднего размера, написанных на Си и С++.

изменения и ошибки - это разные вещи.

но если изменения, то я знаю, где нужно смотреть. Даже статистика неплохая получиться - github.com.

 - выбираем понравившиеся проекты (там можно выбрать популярные)
 - делаем `clone`
 - используя `git log` и Ко (компанию :) ), делаем анализ. В коммитах можно подсмотреть кол-во измененных строк и так далее.
 - автоматизируем процесс.
 - публикуем результаты.

На будущее можно использовать bitbucket, sf, google code.

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо. Хорошая идея, только трудоемкая, может когда-нибудь и воспользуюсь ей.

К сожалению, вопрос не настолько актуален, чтобы сейчас делать такой анализ самому.

Comment: Вопрос абсолютно абстрактный))

Потому, что количество правок кода зависит не от языка, а от кривомозгости постановщика задачи (тима, архитектора проекта, самопишушего программиста).. Потому, что **идеальная** архитектура и программа - не имеет правок. Потому что в идеальную архитектуру добавления ложатся новыми модулями, никак не затрагивая уже имеющиеся. Ну а в идеальной программе - нет багов, которые нужно патчить))

Comment: @SilverIce, количество правок кода зависит от кучи факторов, но *возможно* и от языка тоже.

Так же, как и выбор языка зависит от задачи.

--

Если хотите знать мое мнение, то я считаю, что при решении **похожих** задач на разных языках количество правок будет **разным** (для групп программистов примерно равной квалификации).

Хотел бы убедиться (или разубедиться) в этом, глядя на цифры.

Comment: @avp - правок каких. Есть синтаксические ляпы в коде, есть логические ляпы в коде, есть архитектурные ошибки - это все правки но правки разные))

Да, вполне может быть, что на языках более строгих (С++ напр.) количество синтаксических правок будет выше. На вольношатаюшихся... (скажем РНР) больше будет ошибок связанных с логикой поведения софта. А архитектура - исключительно зависит от проектировщика.

Это исключительно личное мнение человека, регулярно пишущего на РНР, С++, Java, 1C :)

P.S. Где б найти хорошего тестера лучше даже несколько... эти товарищи смогли бы дать точный ответ вам.

Answer (score 3):

На сайте [PVS-studio](http://www.viva64.com/ru/pvs-studio/) есть раздел "Читайте про ошибки, найденные в известных проектах с помощью PVS-Studio". Там написаны отдельные статьи для каждого проекта и, возможно, там будет статистика.

Comment: @Anxis, спасибо!